# Ionic instagram issue

Tags: ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm trying to share image through Instagram by **$cordovaInstagram** or **$cordovaSocialSharing** plugin. But failed to do so. Here is what I did:

1. Install **ngCordova**
2. Modify info.plist

> ```
> <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
>     <dict>
>       <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
>       <true/>
>     </dict>
>     <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
>     <array>
>       <string>fb</string>
>       <string>fbapi</string>
>       <string>fbauth2</string>
>       <string>fbshareextension</string>
>       <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
>       <string>twitter</string>
>       <string>whatsapp</string>
>       <string>wechat</string>
>       <string>line</string>
>       <string>instagram</string>
>     </array>
> ```

3. Install **$cordovaInstagram** and **$cordovaSocialSharing** plugins.

Source code:

```
    // using $cordovaInstagram plugin
    $scope.instagramShare2 = function() {
      $cordovaInstagram.share(imgData, 'Test').then(function() {
          alert('it works');
        }, function(err) {
          alert(err);
        });
    }

    // using $cordovaSocialSharing plugin
    $scope.instagramShare = function() {
      $cordovaSocialSharing
          .shareVia('instagram', message, link, "")
          .then(function(result) {
            alert('shared');
          }, function(err) {
            alert(err);
          });
    }
```

Unfortunately none of them work. It works if I use $cordovaSocialSharing for WhatsApp.

```
$scope.whatsAppShare = function() {
      $cordovaSocialSharing
          .shareViaWhatsApp(message, link, 'http://www.google.com')
          .then(function(result) {
            alert('shared');
          }, function(err) {
            alert(err);
          });
    }
```

Can anybody help? Thanks.

Comment: Please check here https://github.com/vstirbu/InstagramPlugin/issues/23

Comment: also check the example here https://github.com/vstirbu/instagramplugin-example